# PHP - Transform String to Float

Tags: php, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I need to transform a String to a Float.

I will receive Strings like this:

```
$string  = "1.70 m";
$string2 = "2.445 m";
```

How can I easly transform this strings to:

```
$float1 = 1.70;
$float2 = 2.445;
```

Can someone give me some clues?

Best Regards,

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify whether you mean floats or integers. Otherwise I'll do it and assume you mean floats.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are [floats](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php), not [integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). Integers do not have decimal points.

To answer your question, you can simply [typecast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) the strings directly, the conversion will strip off the units as those aren't numeric characters:

```
$string = "1.70 m";
$float = (float) $string;
```

Comment: Great trick! And great help. Thanks for your knowledge. Best Regards.

Comment: Hi, I have been doing come UnitTest's. If I input "m 1.70" will not return "1.70". Any clues how how to solve? Best Regards,

Comment: @André: You may want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

you can get it by

```
echo (float)array_shift(implode(' ', $string));
```

Update :

```
echo (float) $string;
```

Comment: No need for the trouble, a direct cast will strip the space and the units away.

Comment: Yaa..! I got that after your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is probably with the floatval() function:

http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

For exmaple:

```
floatval("1.70 m");
```

gives you:

> 1.7

Answer (score -1):

```
$integer = intval($string);
```

Enjoy :D